# Найти значение в таблице

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть таблица **news** в ней колонка **date**

Есть переменная **$date**

```
$date = '01082020';
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как используя **mysqli** просканировать колонку **date** на наличие содержимого переменной **$date** и выполнить следующие условие:

```
if (...) {
  echo "запись с такой датой не найдена";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf(mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT `date` FROM `news` WHERE `date` = '$date'")) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo 'Есть запись с такой датой.';
    }else{
        echo "Запись с такой датой не найдена.";
    }
}else{
    echo "Не удалось выполнить запрос.";
}
```